# How to get the coordinates from glEvalCoord2f in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I'm using glMap2f(GL_MAP2_VERTEX_3, ...) to draw a nurbs surface. I use glEvalCoord2f to draw triangles and I want to get the coordinates so that I can use them to compute the normals myself or do some other manipulation on CPU (like adding Gaussian noise or whatever). Is it possible to get these coordinates from OpenGL? I don't want to implement nurbs myself and I think that by using OpenGL one can take the advantage of the computing power of the GPU.

Comment: You can probably use the feedback buffer (not to be confused with transform feedback in modern GL) to do this. It will be a lot of work and not particularly portable these days (but then again, neither are evaluators). The thing is, evaluators really are not evaluated on the GPU... if you were trying to take advantage of the GPU, you would need to either use a dedicated library or write your own geometry / tessellation / compute shaders to evaluate your NURBS.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman thanks.  I wonder if there is any light weighted alternative to libnurbs that you know of? I tried it but it seemed too complex and out dated